# How to plot 2 seaborn lmplots side-by-side?

Tags: python, matplotlib, ipython, seaborn

Plotting 2 distplots or scatterplots in a subplot works great:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
%matplotlib inline

# create df
x = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 400)
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': x, 'y': np.sin(x ** 2)})

# Two subplots
f, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, sharey=True)
ax1.plot(df.x, df.y)
ax1.set_title('Sharing Y axis')
ax2.scatter(df.x, df.y)

plt.show()
```

[image: Subplot example]

But when I do the same with an `lmplot` instead of either of the other types of charts I get an error:

> AttributeError: 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'lmplot'

Is there any way to plot these chart types side by side?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You get that error because matplotlib and its objects are completely unaware of seaborn functions.

Pass your axes objects (i.e., `ax1` and `ax2`) to [`seaborn.regplot`](http://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/generated/seaborn.regplot.html#seaborn.regplot) or you can skip defining those and use the `col` kwarg of [`seaborn.lmplot`](http://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/generated/seaborn.lmplot.html#seaborn.lmplot)

With your same imports, pre-defining your axes and using `regplot` looks like this:

```
# create df
x = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 400)
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': x, 'y': np.sin(x ** 2)})
df.index.names = ['obs']
df.columns.names = ['vars']

idx = np.array(df.index.tolist(), dtype='float')  # make an array of x-values

# call regplot on each axes
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2, sharey=True)
sns.regplot(x=idx, y=df['x'], ax=ax1)
sns.regplot(x=idx, y=df['y'], ax=ax2)
```

[image]

Using lmplot requires your [dataframe to be tidy](http://vita.had.co.nz/papers/tidy-data.pdf). Continuing from the code above:

```
tidy = (
    df.stack() # pull the columns into row variables   
      .to_frame() # convert the resulting Series to a DataFrame
      .reset_index() # pull the resulting MultiIndex into the columns
      .rename(columns={0: 'val'}) # rename the unnamed column
)
sns.lmplot(x='obs', y='val', col='vars', hue='vars', data=tidy)
```

[image]

Comment: Is there another way (meanwhile) to plot lmplot side by side? In my case, I don't wanna' split the hue into different subplots but put those lmplots themselves into subplots next to each other. I can't find a way how to do so..

Comment: @Ben I don't understand your comment. Did you try removing the `hue` parameter from the call to `lmplot`?

Comment: Is there a way to combine two lmplots (not regplots) each with multiple axes? For example, I have two lmplots with 1 row and 4 columns. I hope to combine them to a 2 row by 4 column plot

Comment: @XinNiu combine your datasets, and use the `row` parameter in `lmplot`

Answer (score 9):

If the intention of using `lmplot` is to use `hue` for two different sets of variables, `regplot` may not be sufficient without some tweaks.
In order to use of seaborn's `lmplot` `hue` argument in two side-by-side plots, one possible solution is:

```
def hue_regplot(data, x, y, hue, palette=None, **kwargs):
    from matplotlib.cm import get_cmap
    
    regplots = []
    
    levels = data[hue].unique()
    
    if palette is None:
        default_colors = get_cmap('tab10')
        palette = {k: default_colors(i) for i, k in enumerate(levels)}
    
    for key in levels:
        regplots.append(
            sns.regplot(
                x=x,
                y=y,
                data=data[data[hue] == key],
                color=palette[key],
                **kwargs
            )
        )
    
    return regplots
```

This function give result similar to `lmplot` (with `hue` option), but accepts the `ax` argument, necessary for creating a composite figure.
An example of usage is

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
%matplotlib inline

rnd = np.random.default_rng(1234567890)

# create df
x = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 400)
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': x, 'y': np.sin(x ** 2),
                   'color1': rnd.integers(0,2, size=400), 'color2': rnd.integers(0,3, size=400)}) # color for exemplification

# Two subplots
f, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, sharey=True)
# ax1.plot(df.x, df.y)
ax1.set_title('Sharing Y axis')
# ax2.scatter(df.x, df.y)

hue_regplot(data=df, x='x', y='y', hue='color1', ax=ax1)
hue_regplot(data=df, x='x', y='y', hue='color2', ax=ax2)

plt.show()
```

[image: Example of regplots using the hue variable]