# How to make seperate Seaborn kdeplots for all different columns from the same pandas Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, subplot, seaborn

How can I make make two separate Seaborn kdeplots for all the columns of a pandas dataframe:

- A pandas dataframe (`df`) with six columns (e.g. below):

`df.columns = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"]`

I tried the following code, but that did not work. Any tips for the code below?

```
df = sns.load_dataset("df")
g = sns.FacetGrid(df)
g.map(s.skdeplot, "df.columns");
```

Comment: add code to your example that generates your dataframe from scratch (e.g., without reading any files)

Comment: KDEs are (nearly) continuous calculations, what do you mean by "points below 0.5". Do you want the portions of the KDE below and above the threshold to be different colors?

Comment: @PaulH. Changed the question a bit. Please see above. Hope you can help out.

Comment: `df = sns.load_dataset("df")` is throwing an error. Can you make your example reproducible from scratch?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Comment: use the same approach as this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33049884/how-to-plot-2-seaborn-lmplots-side-by-side

Answer (score 4):

I think you need to use `pd.melt`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id1' :np.random.randint(3,size=1000),
               'id2' :['ABC'[i] for i in np.random.randint(3,size=1000)],
               'val1':np.random.normal(loc=1, size=1000),
               'val2':np.random.normal(loc=2, size=1000),
               'val3':np.random.normal(loc=3, size=1000)})

g = sns.FacetGrid(pd.melt(df,
                      id_vars=['id1','id2'],
                      value_vars=['val1','val2','val3']),
              hue='id1',col='id2',row='variable')
g.map(sns.kdeplot,'value')
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is here:

```
ax(i) = sns.kdeplot(dftouse[column], c = colorUp(dftouse[column]))
```

`ax(i)` is a function call. You are trying to assign something to it. That is not correct.

I'm not familiar with matplotlib, just Python. Perhaps did you mean `ax[i]`? If ax is an array or a dict, then this might be correct.

Comment: Changed the question a bit. Please see above. Hope you can help out.

Comment: Seems strange that you have `df.columns` in quotes, but again, I'm not familiar with that package.. (Also, you changed the question entirely. If my comment was helpful, it might have been polite to give me an up-vote or credit for answering it, and then asking a different question in a different thread. I am trying to build some reputation after all.)