# Can you add seaborn plots to matplotlib subplots?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, subplot

```
figures,data= plt.subplots(1,3,figsize=[10,10])

data[0].scatter(columns[3],columns[2])

data[1].hist2d(columns[3],columns[2],cmap='Blues') 

data[2].sns.kdeplot(columns[3],columns[2],cmap='Blues')
```

gives the error: `'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'sns'`

Is there any way around this or would I just have to do a seaborn subplot ?
I find matplotlib  a lot easier.

Comment: [Create the matplotlib figure, pass the axis to seaborn.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33091668/8881141)

Comment: You need `sns.kdeplot(..., ax=data[2])`.  It would be less confusing if you renamed the variable `data` to `axes`. Or you could assign the axes directly as `fig,(ax1,ax2,ax3)=plt.subplots(1,3)`. Also note that `plt.subplots()` creates just one single "figure" and 3 "axes".